# Dúvida: Função de geradores

Tags: python, funções

**Escreva sua própria função de gerador que funciona como a função interna enumerate.
Recorrendo à função assim:**

```
lessons = ["Why Python Programming", "Data Types and Operators", "Control Flow", "Functions", "Scripting"]

for i, lesson in my_enumerate(lessons, 1):
    print("Lesson {}: {}".format(i, lesson))
```

**deve resultar na saída:**

```
Lesson 1: Why Python Programming
Lesson 2: Data Types and Operators
Lesson 3: Control Flow
Lesson 4: Functions
Lesson 5: Scripting
```

**" Então pessoal, estou com muita dificuldade nesse assunto(Geradores), não consigo compreender como posso resolver esse problema , acredito que devo usar a função** *enumerate()* **, mas a minha falta de compreensão do assunto esteja comprometendo as minhas tentativas. "**

```
lessons = ["Why Python Programming", "Data Types and Operators", "Control Flow", "Functions", "Scripting"]

def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    # Implement your generator function here


for i, lesson in my_enumerate(lessons, 1):
    print("Lesson {}: {}".format(i, lesson))
```

Comment: Você pode incluir qual erro está impedindo você de obter êxito com o código?

Comment: @WilliamLio na verdade eu não estou conseguindo nem sequer pensar como devo criar esse código , repito , por eu não compreender o assunto relacionado a geradores .

Comment: Quando li pela primeira vez entendi uma coisa bem diferente, quando reli entendi seu ponto. Achei bem interessante. Ficarei de olho, também quero saber a resposta ;)

Comment: @Barbetta , eu também , eu não estou conseguindo de forma alguma achar ou bolar um código para resolver isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa de saber a fundo de geradores para fazer uma replica do `enumerate`, pois esse é simples. A sua implementação seria algo como:

```
def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    current = start  # começa no numero passado como segundo parametro
    for elem in iterable: 
        yield current, elem  # gera uma nova tupla
        current += 1  # aumenta o numero corrente
```

O `yield` é o responsável pela geração de cada tupla com a posição e o elemento do iterável.

[Veja o exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/BjIWBI)

Este é um tópico de que deve de seguir com alguma calma e de preferência quando já domina os básicos do Python, pois é mais complicado, e ainda tem bastantes pormenores.

Comment: entendi . Perfeito